# JavaScript: Writing to a file in users machine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and I need to save some data on users machine so they can view it. I am using JavaScript, and I have come to know that creating and writing to a file on users machine is not permitted due to security reasons(through old posts mostly). I have come across ways where the users would have to download a file but that is something I do not want to do(I feel it would be something users wont prefer).

I want the data to be stored on users machine as I have a stat that I generate and want my users to access or view it. The data would be manipulated frequently and it must be stored in a text file(say, stat.txt). I was wondering if it is possible or, if there are any alternatives to it.

PS- I'm new to Chrome Extension Development and know basics of JavaScript

Comment: Check out [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)?

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: I went through the **localStorage** too. I understood about the name/value pair and how **setItem** and **getItem** work, but I couldn't think of a way of saving it to a file. Suppose, I have a variable say, _data_ which I want to write to a file say, _stat.txt_. I can't think of a way how **localStorage** will help me.

Comment: @HisabIrpat As you stated, you *can't* save/load directly to/from a file. `localStorage` provides a different means of saving your data.

Comment: You can write it all under one key as a string as long as you do not go over the storage limit. Did you look at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: @MikeC how will I display the result to the user using `localStorage`. I can only manage to display the result in console but i don't want that. I want the users to be able to access the data in a more handy way. I can pop up alerts too but that would be inconvenient for the users.

Comment: @epascarello I have tried the fileSystem APIs too but they don't seem to work(maybe cause I can't figure how to).
The code below doesn't show any error but I can figure where the file is created (if at all). I have even tried `C:\test_log.txt` but still can't get the file.

Comment: @epascarello I was not able to put my code here. [link](http://ideone.com/sD3pzr) This is what I have managed to gather so far

Comment: `C:\whatever` wont work because there is no `C` in javascript :P. Think multi-platform, security etc. Regardless, first you need to get to the bottom of why exactly do you *think* you need it. You can always create a custom page that parses your data (in whatever form it is) and displays it in a 'user-friendly' way to create an illusion of a 'file'. Storage should be regarded as an abstraction. I suggest looking for code snippets for fileSystem API, `indexeddb` or `WebSQL` if that's more your thing.

Comment: So you tried: `localStorage["yourkey"] = "Some string that has your content"; console.log(localStorage["yourKey"]);` and it did not work for you? So if you are really doing a chrome extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @minj A site where I found the implementation of the fileSystem API said that the code _creates an empty file called "log.txt" in the root of the app's file system_ . I tried it but couldn't understand !

Comment: @minj Suppose my chrome extension measures time spent on each site. It should display the data to the user(individual sites along with their time). I could only manage to display the data in the console(the one you access through F12 key) but I want all the data to be written to a file. Something that could be user friendly.

Comment: @epascarello the `console.log(localStorage["yourKey"])` works but I don't want the data on the console. I want the data to be present in a file or something that the user could view easily.

Comment: console is an example... If you want a file, you need to look at the storage api in chrome...

Comment: again with the 'user-friendly'... sigh.. how 'friendly' though? What do you want to allow users to do? P. S. fileSystem API is a virtual file system. Those files don't actually exist

Comment: Okay. Using an HTML page and chrome.storage I am finally able to do it. Thanks people. PS : It looks quite user-friendly :P